# STM32F3 - diffrence between PWM1 and PWM2

Tags: pwm, stm32, timer, stm32f3

Can anyone explain to me wht is the difference between PWM1 and PWM2 in STM32F3 timer configuration? It is mentioned frequently in documentation, however I can't find the difference between these two settings. Code example for setting PWM1 OC mode for timer 8:

```
Tim_InitStruct.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
Tim_InitStruct.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
Tim_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse = 512 / 2; // 50%
Tim_InitStruct.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is documented in the Reference Manual, at the register descriptions.

> **TIMx capture/compare mode register 1 (TIMx_CCMR1)**
>
> [...]
>
> 0110: PWM mode 1 - In upcounting, channel 1 is active as long as TIMx_CNT<TIMx_CCR1
>   else inactive. In downcounting, channel 1 is inactive (OC1REF='0) as long as
>   TIMx_CNT>TIMx_CCR1 else active (OC1REF=1).
>
> 0111: PWM mode 2 - In upcounting, channel 1 is inactive as long as
>   TIMx_CNT<TIMx_CCR1 else active. In downcounting, channel 1 is active as long as
>   TIMx_CNT>TIMx_CCR1 else inactive.

In other words, the output signal is inverted in mode 2.